Filter In-Store Pickup Locations based on stock
I am trying to get round a bug in Magento In-Store pickup, https://github.com/magento/inventory/issues/3367
I have multiple pickup locations, stock is assigned to the relevant location but Magento always shows all locations even if its out of stock.
I have been looking at GetPickupLocationIntersectionForSkus.php but I cant see how to filter the results to only show souces that have stock
    public function execute(array $skus): array
    {
        $select = $this->sourceItemResource->getConnection()->select();
        $expression = $this->expressionFactory->create(['expression' => 'COUNT(' . SourceItemInterface::SKU . ')']);
        $select->from($this->sourceItemResource->getMainTable())
            ->joinInner(
                $this->sourceResource->getMainTable(),
                $this->sourceItemResource->getMainTable() . '.' . SourceItemInterface::SOURCE_CODE . '=' .
                $this->sourceResource->getMainTable() . '.' . SourceInterface::SOURCE_CODE
            )
            ->where(SourceItemInterface::SKU . ' in (?) ', $skus)
            ->where(SourceInterface::ENABLED . ' = 1')
            ->where(PickupLocationInterface::IS_PICKUP_LOCATION_ACTIVE . ' = 1')
            ->reset(Select::COLUMNS)
            ->columns([SourceItemInterface::SOURCE_CODE])
            ->group($this->sourceItemResource->getMainTable() . '.' . SourceItemInterface::SOURCE_CODE)
            ->having($expression . ' = ' . count($skus));
        $result = $this->sourceItemResource->getConnection()->fetchAssoc($select);
        $sourceCodes = [];
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $sourceCodes[] = $row[SourceItemInterface::SOURCE_CODE];
        }

        return $sourceCodes;
    }

I thought adding ->where(SourceItemInterface::STATUS . ' = 1') would do the trick but this still shows the sources where the item is out of stock
